# ¿Como validar un campo de un formulario con una ventana de alerta de popup?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Estoy tratando de cambiar el  `alert`  básico que trae por default el  `javascript` y llamar un popup que tengo creado, pero no he logrado conseguir como llamar para que me salga esa ventana emergente algo mas personalizado, ahorita lo tengo en  `display:none;` para que no se muestre, pero me gustaría saber de que manera puedo ejecutarlo.

```css
.container1{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background:  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}


 .popup1{
  width: 400px;
  background: #ffff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;

}

.popup1 p{
  margin: 10px 0 10px;
}

.popup1 img{
width: 50px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO</h1>
    
    
    <!-- FORMULARIO DE CONTACTO-->
    
    <form class="mx-auto">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="itNombre" placeholder="Nombre*" name="nombre">
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itEmail" placeholder="Email*" name="email">
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-auto">
    
    <textarea type="text"  class="form-control" id="itMensaje" placeholder="Mensaje*" name="mensaje"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" id="btn-enviar" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="validarform();">ENVIAR</button>
  </div>
</form>


<!--POPUP VENTANA DE ALERTA-->

<div  class="container1" id="popup-1">

  <div class="popup1">
   <img src="https://svgsilh.com/svg/98739-ff9800.svg">
   <P>!Favor de llenar el campo nombre!</p>
   <button type="button">CERRAR</button>
  </div>
</div>
  
     <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
></script>
  
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
function validarform(){

      var nombre = $('#itNombre').val();
      var email = $('#itEmail').val();
      var mensaje = $('#itMensaje').val();
      
     if (nombre =="") {
        $('#itNombre')
       alert("¡Favor de llenar el campo Nombre!");
      return false;
     }else if (email =="") {
      $('#iEmail')
      alert("¡Favor de llenar el campo Email!");
      return false;
    }else if (mensaje =="") {
      $('#itMensaje')
      alert("¡Favor de llenar el campo Mensaje!");
      return false;
    }
     
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: El `container1` y su botón debe tener una clase `toggle()` dentro de cada if

Answer (score 0):

Existe el elemento [dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog) el cual permite es una ventana emergente y permite personalizarla a través de CSS (no así el elemento `alert` que no permite personalización alguna)

En la documentación que te he enlazado explica bien su uso, incluido el CSS. Lo más notable es el pseudoelemento `::backdrop` el cual es una capa que se sobrepone al contenido para dar la sensación que lo de abajo queda bloqueado.

Por último javascript tiene la propiedad de poder sobrescribir funciones, por lo que fácilmente puedes sobrescribir `alert` por una función que genere un `dialog`

Ejemplo:

```js
window.alert = (mensaje="", titulo = "") => {
    const dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
    dialog.innerHTML = `
    <header>
        ${titulo}
    </header>
    <div class="content">
       ${mensaje}
    </div>
    <footer>
        <button data-action="cerrar">Aceptar</button>
    </footer>`;

    dialog.querySelectorAll("[data-action='cerrar']").forEach(a => {
        a.addEventListener("click", function () {
          dialog.close();
          
          //este evento es para remover el dialog cuando termine la animación
          //si no existe animación de salida, simplemente dejar: dialog.remove()
          dialog.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function () {
            dialog.removeEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', arguments.callee, false);
            dialog.remove()
          });

        });
    });
    document.body.appendChild(dialog);
    dialog.showModal();
}


alert("¡Favor de llenar el campo Nombre!", "Error");
```

```css
::backdrop {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    magenta,
    rebeccapurple,
    dodgerblue,
    green
  );
  opacity: 0.75;
}

dialog{
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color: #565252;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 1px #000000b8;
  padding: 0;
}

dialog > header{
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

dialog > footer{
  display:flex;
  border-top:1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  justify-content: end;
}

dialog > .content{
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

dialog {
  animation: fade-out 0.3s ease-out;
}

dialog[open] {
  animation: fade-in 0.3s ease-out;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    display: none;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    display: block;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scaleY(1);
    display: block;
  }

  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scaleY(0);
    display: none;
  }
}
```